# Float left not working as expected

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox, css-float

I have 4 divs that has display:flex row that is floated left. I am trying to get it to be responsive when screen size is shrunk. However, the blocks wont move.The .box supposedly break whenever it touches the border. Here is the code:

```css
body{
  background-color:grey;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  float:left;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out, transform .2s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #4aa8ea;
}

.zoom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s, filter 2s;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box:hover .zoom {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.centerImg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.ttl {
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:20px;
}

.desc {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size:10px;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:white;
}

.wrapper {
  -webkit-column-width: 150px;
  column-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Animal Collection</h1>
    <p>Get a look at all the species!</p>

    <div class="outer">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://www.owlsecurity.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/buho.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">OWL</div>
        <div class="desc">
          <div class="wrapper"> The owl is a very fascinating species that is nocturnal. It is considered as a predator</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/70/a1/58/70a1580630e2233978c0755f7215a3a2.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">CAT</div>
        <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The cat or feline is a descendant of a lion. It can jump as high as 13 feet </div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d7/3a/63d73ab34ef22437a2525e0e715f68c8.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">TOUCAN</div>
        <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The Toucan is an exotic bird that comes from Brazil. It eats fruits and vegetables and is considered a herbivore.</div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d7/3a/63d73ab34ef22437a2525e0e715f68c8.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">TOUCAN</div>
        <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The Toucan is an exotic bird that comes from Brazil. It eats fruits and vegetables and is considered a herbivore.</div></div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    


  </body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help, here is the fiddle: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s479vovz/100/)**

**SOLUTION:**
Adding flex-wrap:wrap; to the .outer class resolves the issue

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong here?”_ - you left `flex-wrap` at the default value `nowrap` ...

Comment: add `flex-wrap:wrap` to outer `div` will solve it.

Comment: Thank you :), what does flex-wrap do? @Chilll007

Comment: i post it as answer which will give you complete guide to flexbox.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the transition less snappier? @Chilll007

Comment: which transition?

Comment: So that it does not only snap in place, but also animate the movement of the moving box @Chilll007

Comment: are you talking about the hover animation transition or box wrapping transition?

Comment: So, as the windows shrink, if one of the box moves under, the animation will trigger and hovers the box under instead of just snapping it into place @Chilll007

Comment: If you want to animate the box which moves under I don't think so its possible by CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: You just need to add "flex-wrap: wrap;" in .outer div because "display: flex;" need wrap div so i have used "flex-wrap: wrap;".

Comment: Thank you for your help :), is there any way to make the transition smoother and less snappy?

Comment: i think this works "transition: all 3s ease-in-out;"

Answer (score 2):

Flex wrap is wrapped the content inside the display flex parent width which shrinks the child's to adjust to the parent width so they will fit in one line.

```
flex-wrap: wrap
```

will wrap the content in same as word-wrap where if content is flowing outside the parent div it will wrap them to another line.

here is the complete guide to flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-4 which gives you idea about the all flexbox properties.

Answer (score 1):

Change `flex-direction:row` to `flex-flow: row wrap;`:

```css
body{
  background-color:grey;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  float:left;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 2s ease-out, transform .2s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #4aa8ea;
}

.zoom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: transform 2s, filter 2s;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box:hover .zoom {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.centerImg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.ttl {
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:20px;
}

.desc {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size:10px;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:white;
}

.wrapper {
  -webkit-column-width: 150px;
  column-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Animal Collection</h1>
    <p>Get a look at all the species!</p>

    <div class="outer">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="http://www.owlsecurity.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/buho.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">OWL</div>
        <div class="desc">
          <div class="wrapper"> The owl is a very fascinating species that is nocturnal. It is considered as a predator</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/70/a1/58/70a1580630e2233978c0755f7215a3a2.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">CAT</div>
        <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The cat or feline is a descendant of a lion. It can jump as high as 13 feet </div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d7/3a/63d73ab34ef22437a2525e0e715f68c8.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">TOUCAN</div>
        <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The Toucan is an exotic bird that comes from Brazil. It eats fruits and vegetables and is considered a herbivore.</div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d7/3a/63d73ab34ef22437a2525e0e715f68c8.png" class="zoom centerImg">
        <div class="ttl">TOUCAN</div>
        <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The Toucan is an exotic bird that comes from Brazil. It eats fruits and vegetables and is considered a herbivore.</div></div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :), is there any way to make the transition smoother and less snappy?

Answer (score 0):

Updated JSFiddle:

```
  https://jsfiddle.net/s479vovz/145/
```

HTML:

```
<h1>Animal Collection</h1>
<p>Get a look at all the species!</p>

<div class="outer">
  <div style="width:25%;margin-right:1%;">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://www.owlsecurity.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/buho.png" class="zoom centerImg">
    <div class="ttl">OWL</div>
    <div class="desc">
      <div class="wrapper"> The owl is a very fascinating species that is nocturnal. It is considered as a predator</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width:23%;margin-right:1%;">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/70/a1/58/70a1580630e2233978c0755f7215a3a2.png" class="zoom centerImg">
    <div class="ttl">CAT</div>
    <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The cat or feline is a descendant of a lion. It can jump as high as 13 feet </div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width:23%;margin-right:1%;">  
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d7/3a/63d73ab34ef22437a2525e0e715f68c8.png" class="zoom centerImg">
    <div class="ttl">TOUCAN</div>
    <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The Toucan is an exotic bird that comes from Brazil. It eats fruits and vegetables and is considered a herbivore.</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width:23%;margin-right:1%;"> 
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d7/3a/63d73ab34ef22437a2525e0e715f68c8.png" class="zoom centerImg">
    <div class="ttl">TOUCAN</div>
    <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The Toucan is an exotic bird that comes from Brazil. It eats fruits and vegetables and is considered a herbivore.</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width:23%;margin-right:1%;">  
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/63/d7/3a/63d73ab34ef22437a2525e0e715f68c8.png" class="zoom centerImg">
    <div class="ttl">TOUCAN</div>
    <div class="desc"><div class="wrapper"> The Toucan is an exotic bird that comes from Brazil. It eats fruits and vegetables and is considered a herbivore.</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background-color:grey;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  background-color: skyblue;
  /* width: 180px; */
  height: 250px;
  margin: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: background-color 1s ease-out;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-out, transform .2s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #4aa8ea;
}

.zoom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transition: transform 1s, filter 1s;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box:hover .zoom {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.centerImg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 77px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 13px;
}

.ttl {
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:20px;
}

.desc {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size:10px;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:white;
}

.wrapper {
  -webkit-column-width: 150px;
  column-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}
```